# ASP.NET MVC 4 mobile web app -deployment error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having some trouble to deploy the mobile web app that I made using mvc 4.

the server error is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: you did update the web.config http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes point 7 with regard to the assemblyBindig?

Comment: That dont help..still the same error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the server has the MVC 4 dll's instead of MVC 3's

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC 4 uses version 2 of WebPages (Razor). So it requires System.Web.Helpers, Version 2.0.0.0 to be present on the target machine. Either you install it from the package or you could also do a [bin deployment](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) so that you don't need to install ASP.NET MVC 4 on the target server. Obviously all the required assemblies must in this case be included as explained in the blog post.